# Bitbucket Cloud for Slack App Branch Pattern Match Notifications Not Working

Tags: notifications, bitbucket, glob, slack, pull-request

We are trying to set up the [Bitbucket Cloud for Slack app](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-cloud-for-slack-945096776.html) to get automatic notifications in our team A Slack channel when I create a Pull Request in a team B repository. In order to avoid being overwhelmed with notifications when other contributers in that team B repo create Pull Requests, we're trying to use a glob pattern match on the branch name. My branch names all begin with "SC-" (Jira issue key values). Seems we've tried every possible pattern. However, notifications aren't coming up when I'm creating PRs on my team B repo branches.

After further testing, we've only been able to obtain a branch name match and PR creation notification using the `*` pattern (without quotes).

Wondering if anyone else has come across this issue? And, if so, have you been able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The branch name filter in the subscription settings refers to the target branch - not the source branch.  As a result this use case isn't supported by bitbucket cloud out of the box